# liferay dynamic datalist getfieldvalue for radio and select fields contains cruft

Tags: liferay-6, dynamic-data, liferay-velocity

How do I remove the extra [" "] when retrieving DynamicDataList data from LifeRay 6.1.30 using DDLRecordLocalService getFieldValue in a velocity template for radio or select fields.

Here is my VM:

```
#set ($ddlRecordsUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService"))
#set ($records = ${ddlRecordsUtil.getRecords($getterUtil.getLong($reserved_record_set_id.data))})
<ul>
#foreach ($record in $records)
<li>
    $record.getFieldValue("radio1477"), 
    $record.getFieldValue("select2047")
</li>
#end
</ul>
```

Where radio1477 is:

```
<input name="radio1477" value="arf">arf
<input name="radio1477" value="bark">bark
<input name="radio1477" value="woof">woof
```

and select2047 is

```
<select name="select2047">
<option value="arf"> arf </option>
<option value="bark"> bark </option>
<option value="woof"> woof </option>
</select>
```

Returns the following list:

- ["arf"], ["arf"]
- ["bark"], ["bark"]
- ["woof"], ["woof"]

What is the best way to remove the [" "] cruft?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to receive the field-value is to get the field first and then use `getRenderedValue($locale)`.

```
...
#set ($fields = $record.getFields())
#set ($myField = $fields.get("myselect"))
#set ($myValue = $myField.getRenderedValue($locale)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best way but it did remove the [" "] cruft.

```
#set($arf = $record.getFieldValue("radio1477"))
#set($arflen = $arf.length() - 2)
#if ($arflen > 2)
    $arf.substring(2, $arflen)
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

John,

Retrieve it from serviceContext; something like this should work.

${serviceContext.getAttribute("$field")}

Iterate over the fields of the individual records